# Is there a better way to combine hundreds of SELECT queries for optimal performance?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.

My application has to periodically execute hundreds of queries which correspond to users' Saved Searches, to check if new items have arrived that match their criteria.

Currently the queries are executed one at a time in a loop, which takes ***Way Too Long (TM)***.

So after some Internet searching and discarding alternatives such as having the application execute multiple queries in parallel, I stumbled onto the idea of combining the queries with a UNION so that they can be executed all at once. Here's a little sampler of what that looks like. I pulled just three queries as a Proof Of Concept and for illustration purposes:

```
with t1 as (select 1, id from retsview where ((zip5=92101) AND searchablePrice>=1000000 AND searchablePrice<=2000000 AND beds>=4 AND FB>=3 AND (ctcSortOrder>'2018-02-28 01:15:04 UTC' AND ctcSortOrder<='2018-03-01 06:15:00 UTC') AND ctcValidTo>'2018-03-01 06:15:00 UTC' AND ctcValidFrom<='2018-03-01 06:15:00 UTC') order by lstDate desc, ctcSortOrder desc LIMIT 9999),
t2 as (select 2, id from retsview where ((geoinfo::jsonb->'boundaries' ?| array['Zip Code: 92069','Zip Code: 92078','Zip Code: 92096']) AND searchablePrice>=350000 AND searchablePrice<=500000 AND beds>=3 AND FB>=2 AND (ctcSortOrder>'2018-04-20 17:59:00 UTC' AND ctcSortOrder<='2018-04-21 18:00:00 UTC') AND ctcValidTo>'2018-04-21 18:00:00 UTC' AND ctcValidFrom<='2018-04-21 18:00:00 UTC') order by lstDate desc, ctcSortOrder desc LIMIT 9999),
t3 as (select 3, id from retsview where ((zip5=92122 OR zip5=92093) AND searchablePrice>=400000 AND searchablePrice<=800000 AND HOAFee<=800.0 AND beds>=2 AND FB>=1 AND (numHB>=1 OR FB>1) AND (ctcSortOrder>'2020-03-19 17:00:00 UTC' AND ctcSortOrder<='2020-03-20 17:55:00 UTC') AND ctcValidTo>'2020-03-20 17:55:00 UTC' AND ctcValidFrom<='2020-03-20 17:55:00 UTC') order by lstDate desc, ctcSortOrder desc LIMIT 9999)
select * from t1 union select * from t2 union select * from t3
```

And here's what the EXPLAIN looks like:
[image]

So here's my question ... what is the "correct" way to structure a composite query so that it can scale to hundreds of subqueries most optimally? In particular, I am wondering whether scans of the same index (`searchrunner_composite` seen above) can be merged by the optimizer into a single scan.

**UPDATE:  EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)**

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=741.56..741.59 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=1.113..1.130 rows=94 loops=1)
   Output: t1."?column?", t1.id
   Group Key: t1."?column?", t1.id
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 32kB
   Buffers: shared hit=480
   ->  Append  (cost=90.09..741.55 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.328..1.088 rows=94 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=480
         ->  Subquery Scan on t1  (cost=90.09..90.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.328..0.355 rows=90 loops=1)
               Output: t1."?column?", t1.id
               Buffers: shared hit=132
               ->  Limit  (cost=90.09..90.09 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.327..0.341 rows=90 loops=1)
                     Output: 1, t1_1.id, t1_1.lstdate, t1_1.ctcsortorder
                     Buffers: shared hit=132
                     ->  Sort  (cost=90.09..90.09 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.326..0.332 rows=90 loops=1)
                           Output: 1, t1_1.id, t1_1.lstdate, t1_1.ctcsortorder
                           Sort Key: t1_1.lstdate DESC, t1_1.ctcsortorder DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=132
                           ->  Index Scan using searchrunner_composite on public.rets t1_1  (cost=0.43..90.08 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.055..0.296 rows=90 loops=1)
                                 Output: 1, t1_1.id, t1_1.lstdate, t1_1.ctcsortorder
                                 Index Cond: ((t1_1.ctcsortorder > '2018-02-28 01:15:04+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_1.ctcsortorder <= '2018-03-01 06:15:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_1.ctcvalidto > '2018-03-01 06:15:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_1.ctcvalidfrom <= '2018-03-01 06:15:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_1.searchableprice >= 1000000) AND (t1_1.searchableprice <= 2000000) AND (t1_1.beds >= 4) AND (t1_1.fb >= 3))
                                 Filter: (t1_1.zip5 = 92130)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 36
                                 Buffers: shared hit=132
         ->  Subquery Scan on t2  (cost=126.66..126.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.134..0.136 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: t2."?column?", t2.id
               Buffers: shared hit=49
               ->  Limit  (cost=126.66..126.67 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.133..0.135 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Output: 2, t1_2.id, t1_2.lstdate, t1_2.ctcsortorder
                     Buffers: shared hit=49
                     ->  Sort  (cost=126.66..126.67 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.133..0.134 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Output: 2, t1_2.id, t1_2.lstdate, t1_2.ctcsortorder
                           Sort Key: t1_2.lstdate DESC, t1_2.ctcsortorder DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=49
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=24.50..126.65 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.098..0.132 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Output: 2, t1_2.id, t1_2.lstdate, t1_2.ctcsortorder
                                 Buffers: shared hit=49
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.geoinfo  (cost=24.07..50.36 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.042..0.064 rows=5 loops=1)
                                       Output: geoinfo.id, geoinfo.value
                                       Recheck Cond: (((geoinfo.value)::jsonb -> 'boundaries'::text) ?| '{"Zip Code: 92069","Zip Code: 92078","Zip Code: 92096"}'::text[])
                                       Heap Blocks: exact=4
                                       Buffers: shared hit=13
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_boundaries  (cost=0.00..24.07 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=5 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: (((geoinfo.value)::jsonb -> 'boundaries'::text) ?| '{"Zip Code: 92069","Zip Code: 92078","Zip Code: 92096"}'::text[])
                                             Buffers: shared hit=9
                                 ->  Index Scan using searchrunner_geo on public.rets t1_2  (cost=0.43..8.47 rows=1 width=42) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=5)
                                       Output: t1_2.id, t1_2.cdrmrfee, t1_2.fb, t1_2.hoafee, t1_2.askprclow, t1_2.beds, t1_2.ctcremovaltimestamp, t1_2.ctcsortorder, t1_2.ctcvalidfrom, t1_2.ctcvalidto, t1_2.estsf, t1_2.isavailable, t1_2.isonlastsync, t1_2.lastsync, t1_2.latitude, t1_2.listprice, t1_2.longitude, t1_2.lstdate, t1_2.numhb, t1_2.oceandistance, t1_2.parkinggaragespaces, t1_2.photocount, t1_2.propertytype, t1_2.searchableprice, t1_2.source, t1_2.stry, t1_2.systemid, t1_2.unspnum, t1_2.updtdate, t1_2.yrblt, t1_2.zip5, t1_2.addressinfo_id, t1_2.cmplx_id, t1_2.community_id, t1_2.geoinfo_id, t1_2.neighborhd_id, t1_2.rawdata_id, t1_2.resourceclass_id, t1_2.searchablekeywords_id, t1_2.status_id
                                       Index Cond: ((t1_2.geoinfo_id = geoinfo.id) AND (t1_2.ctcsortorder > '2018-04-20 17:59:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_2.ctcsortorder <= '2018-04-21 18:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                       Filter: ((t1_2.searchableprice >= 350000) AND (t1_2.searchableprice <= 500000) AND (t1_2.beds >= 3) AND (t1_2.fb >= 2) AND (t1_2.ctcvalidto > '2018-04-21 18:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_2.ctcvalidfrom <= '2018-04-21 18:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 6
                                       Buffers: shared hit=36
         ->  Subquery Scan on t3  (cost=524.71..524.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.585..0.586 rows=3 loops=1)
               Output: t3."?column?", t3.id
               Buffers: shared hit=299
               ->  Limit  (cost=524.71..524.71 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.584..0.585 rows=3 loops=1)
                     Output: 3, t1_3.id, t1_3.lstdate, t1_3.ctcsortorder
                     Buffers: shared hit=299
                     ->  Sort  (cost=524.71..524.71 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.584..0.584 rows=3 loops=1)
                           Output: 3, t1_3.id, t1_3.lstdate, t1_3.ctcsortorder
                           Sort Key: t1_3.lstdate DESC, t1_3.ctcsortorder DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=299
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.rets t1_3  (cost=54.83..524.70 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.312..0.581 rows=3 loops=1)
                                 Output: 3, t1_3.id, t1_3.lstdate, t1_3.ctcsortorder
                                 Recheck Cond: ((t1_3.ctcsortorder > '2020-03-19 17:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcsortorder <= '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcvalidto > '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcvalidfrom <= '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.searchableprice >= 400000) AND (t1_3.searchableprice <= 800000) AND (t1_3.beds >= 2) AND (t1_3.fb >= 1))
                                 Filter: ((t1_3.hoafee <= '800'::double precision) AND ((t1_3.zip5 = 92122) OR (t1_3.zip5 = 92093)) AND ((t1_3.numhb >= 1) OR (t1_3.fb > 1)))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 269
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=264
                                 Buffers: shared hit=299
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on searchrunner_composite  (cost=0.00..54.83 rows=120 width=0) (actual time=0.130..0.130 rows=296 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((t1_3.ctcsortorder > '2020-03-19 17:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcsortorder <= '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcvalidto > '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.ctcvalidfrom <= '2020-03-20 17:55:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (t1_3.searchableprice >= 400000) AND (t1_3.searchableprice <= 800000) AND (t1_3.beds >= 2) AND (t1_3.fb >= 1))
                                       Buffers: shared hit=15
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=13
 Planning Time: 1.888 ms
 Execution Time: 1.210 ms
(77 rows)
```

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: The query runs about 2 **milli**seconds. This wouldn't qualify as "way too long" for me. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: Those 2 milliseconds are very misleading... because 1) I ran this twice and the second time was heavily cached, 2) this is only 3 queries for illustrative purposes, reality is several hundred queries, and also 3) the Way Too Long is when the queries are run in a loop, so per-query overhead is added --- which was my original problem before I rewrote into a single UNION query as shown

Comment: @AlexR: You should have published the slow query plan, the first one. Now we only have the 2ms query. A query with just 3 subqueries is also very different from a query with hundreds of subqueries. What might help, is to put more conditions/columns in the indexes to avoid filtering afterwards, the "rows removed by filter".

Answer (score 0):

> My application has to periodically execute hundreds of queries which
> correspond to users' Saved Searches, to check if new items have
> arrived that match their criteria.

Not an answer to your question, but why don't you search for users when a new item arrives?

And your question can not be answered without details, the original output in plain text from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) or something like that.

Comment: "why don't you search for users when a new item arrives" -> That is an interesting idea. There is some separation of concerns between the item maintenance and the notification component which might make that a larger refactoring effort versus just micro-optimizing the query mechanism.

Comment: I'm updating the question with the output from  EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)